# xml line ending file_put_content

Tags: php, xml, file-get-contents

I'am grabing a file from an external website with : `$xml = file_get_contents($url);`, parsing it and storing it on my own server for further use with `file_put_contents($dir.'/'.$filename, $xml);`

However, when I try to parse the file saved on my server (Ubuntu Server + Nginx), I get an error due to the presence of `\n`that replaced the line break. I understand that there is a problem with the way line breaks are put when using `file_put_content` but I didn't find any similar topic with a solution online.

Might be important to mention that I currently only use the php CLI to execute my php files.

Thanks,
Julien

Comment: If you'd just store the XMl without doing anything, nothing should be changed. What does this _'parsing it'_ before storing entail?

Comment: I parse it for data but dont modify the `$xml`var

Comment: Well, if content is altered, there must be _something_ doing it, and I have a hard time believing it is `file_put_contents`. Could you share a minimal code example which exhibits this unwanted behavior?

Comment: Following your instructions, I tried to recreate the error and It seems that I had twice the same variable name creating the error... such a stupid mistake, thanks for your time Wrikken.